# How to prevent adding XML element if XElement is Null?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xelement

I have a simple XML document that looks like this:

```
<Person>
  <LastName>LastName1</LastName>
  <FirstName>FirstName1</FirstName>
  <MiddleName>MiddleName1</MiddleName>
  <Suffix>Suffix1</Suffix>
</Person>
```

However I have a constraint where I am *not* allowed to add empty tags. Therefore if the `Suffix` value does not exist, I cannot use `<Suffix />` or validation will fail.

I'm composing the XML structure using `XElement` objects from different classes that return their respective XML via a returned `XElement` object from a `.ToXML()` method. I need to check *per element* to see if the XElement being returned is `null`. If that's the case it has to be like that line never existed. I'm trying to use the `??` operator but I'm getting the error that ***?? left operand is never null***. I had the code as follows:

```
public XElement ToXML()
{
  return new XElement("Employee",
    new XElement(this.LastName.ToXML()) ?? null,
    new XElement(this.FirstName.ToXML()) ?? null,
    new XElement(this.MiddleName.ToXML()) ?? null,
    new XElement(this.Suffix.ToXML()) ?? null);
}
```

How can I check per XML node to see if the `XElement` object being returned is null and if so ignore adding/composing that node all together? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What is the return type of `ToXML()` method? If it is `XElement`, why are you creating a new `XElement` around it?

Comment: No you are correct and I should not have used `new` when the method already returns a `XElement` instance. I should have not put that in the sample, but I will leave it for future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A constructor in C# will either return a non-null reference to the object or will throw an exception. It will not return null*.

As for your problem, why not:

```
return new XElement("Employee",
    this.LastName.ToXML(),
    this.FirstName.ToXML(),
    this.MiddleName.ToXML(),
    this.Suffix.ToXML());
```

And just have each of those `ToXML` methods return `null` if none exist?

Or if your case is the properties themselves are null:

```
return new XElement("Employee",
    this.LastName != null ? this.LastName.ToXML() : null, /* null is ignored */
    this.FirstName != null ? this.FirstName.ToXML() : null,
    this.MiddleName != null ? this.MiddleName.ToXML() : null,
    this.Suffix != null ? this.Suffix.ToXML() : null);
```

I also just realized perhaps you always get back an `XElement`, but it may be *empty*, in that case:

```
var elements = new[] { this.LastName.ToXML(), this.FirstName.ToXML(), ...

// use IsEmpty to filter out those that are <Element/>
return new XElement("Employee",
    elements.Where(ee => ee != null && !ee.IsEmpty));
```

<sub>*I believe there is an interesting edge case where you could get this from a COM interface instantiation, but we'll ignore all "strange" coding.</sub>

Comment: If I went with your 1st method and it returns `null`, then you say it will automatically not be added a node to the `XElement` root correct? Mening I don't have to explicitly check as I thought and in your 2nd sample?

Comment: @atconway: that is correct, if they return `null` that is fine. Obviously it can't be added as a node as there is nothing it could know about the node, attribute, etc to add.

Comment: If the ordering of the elements in `elements` shown in your 3rd sample are *preserved* then I think that seems to be a decent solution too.

Comment: @atconway: Yes they are preserved.

Comment: So the only reason to use #3 is when my methods *always* return an instance of `XElement` (even if empty) as opposed to returning `null`? If `null` *can* be returned than #1 is probably best, correct? Want to make sure I understand *when* I need to explicitly check for `null` vs. not having to.

Comment: @atconway: Yes the 3rd method is useful if they always return it. I included the null check to "future" proof against an exception being thrown in the `Where` clause.

Comment: very nice, thank you sir.

Answer (score 3):

You should be using this code instead:

```
public XElement ToXML()
{
    var children = new[]
    {
        this.LastName.ToXML(),
        this.FirstName.ToXML(),
        this.MiddleName.ToXML(),
        this.Suffix.ToXML()
    };

    return new XElement("Employee", children.Where(x => x != null));
}
```

Please note that your code has several issues:

1. The null-coalescing operator (??) is an operator that returns the right hand value when the left hand value is `null`. Making the right hand value `null` is completely useless.
2. Mixing a `new` statement with the ?? operator is completely useless, too, because the result of `new` will never be `null`.
3. The `new XElement` part also seems pretty useless. I assume that `ToXML` already returns an `XElement`, so why create a new instance?

Comment: Correct on #3, it was indeed useless because the method already returns the element.